# Regex combine statements to match everything after last > and before last _

Tags: sql, regex

Pretty new to regex so I am having some trouble combining two statements to get my output. Here is the string I am working on:

```
UI - bridge.dashboard>dashboard_dialog>ipm_dismiss_secondary_1806-ENPF-PrReEm-00-8492678
```

I am attempting to extract everything after the last greater than sign and before the last underscore. This would be my desired output:

```
ipm_dismiss_secondary
```

So far I have been able to access everything after the greater than using this:

```
[^>]*$
```

Which returns:

```
ipm_dismiss_secondary_1806-ENPF-PrReEm-00-8492678
```

Everything before the last underscore using this:

```
.*(?=\_)
```

Which returns:

```
UI - bridge.dashboard>dashboard_dialog>ipm_dismiss_secondary
```

However, for the life of me cannot figure out how to combine these two statements together to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `([^>]+)_[^_]*$`. The first capture group contains what you wish to extract.

After the capture group, we match an `_`, repeat non-underscore characters any number of times and then match a line break.

https://regexr.com/3tatl

---

If that is not satisfactory, you could use [positive look-aheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead: `[^>]+(?=_[^_]*$)`.

https://regexr.com/3tato

Comment: The second one works perfectly! The first placed the desired outcome in the Group 1 match, which is one thing I was confused about while attempting this. How do you opt for the Group 1 match as opposed to the Full match? Now to try and break down the second answer so I can understand where I went wrong, thank you so much!

Comment: @Chapin23 look for "extracting capture groups from regex matches" in your language's documentation. I'm not familiar with SQL really.

Comment: @Chapin23 I've added a link to some information about positive look-aheads. That should explain how the second solution works. TLDR; look-aheads check for the presence or absence of a pattern without matching it.